# Solving the partial deriative by definition, what to do with constants?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

If I want to find a partial deriative by of `y=2x-5+4z-(xz+57)` for x, by definition, just like simple deriative, what I should to do with constants? By definition, I mean trought limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function $y$ is a function of two variables, namely $y(x,z)$. The definition of the partial derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ is given by

$$ \frac{\partial y(x,z)}{\partial x} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{y(x+h,z) - y(x,z)}{h} $$

In our case this evaluates to

\begin{align}
&\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{2(x+h)-5+4z-((x+h)z + 57) - 2x + 5 -4z +xz + 57}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(2x + 2h + 4z -xz -hz-62) -(2x+4z-62-xz)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(2h-hz) + (2x + 4z -xz-62) -(2x+4z-62-xz)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h(2-z)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0}2-z = 2-z
\end{align}

Comment: Why there is h, instead of delta x in the denominator?

Comment: Do you mean in the first equation? Because it is just stating the definition of a partial derivative. You can also find this definition on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Basic_definition)

Comment: Didn't understand, why dx changes to h. It's the growth of the argument, right?

Comment: The partial derivative quantifies what happens when you change one of its variables a little bit. You could write: $\frac{\partial y(x,z)}{\partial x} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{y(x + \Delta x, z) - y(x,z)}{\Delta x} =  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{y(x+h,z) - y(x,z)}{h}$. Then at the end we write $h$ for $\Delta x$ which is a common practice.

Comment: Now understood, just pretty stupid. But, if we will solve it by rules, we assume that that `z` is constant, so it equals 0, how we could get 2-z in the ending?

Comment: Let $f(x,z) = xz$ and $g(x,z)=z$. Then you can easily verify that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = z$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = 0$. Does this clear things up for you?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot

Comment: Just a moment: I got `lim[Δx->0] 2Δx - z` int  the end. Why Δx disapeared in your answer? If Δx moves to zero, it should be `0.00... - z = 0 - z = - z` , no?

Comment: Editted my answer to show explicit steps.